# Is there a way to force close an opened COM port device?

Tags: python, device, pyserial, pyvisa

Using Python, I need to force close a COM port which was opened using a different program. I can't close the COM port because I can't initiate a session with it since its already opened somewhere else.

```
import visa

rm = visa.ResourceManager()

# list all the COM ports connected to PC
print(rm.list_resources())

# open a device session on one COM port
dev = rm.open_resource('COM12')
# this can't be done if the 'COM12' is already opened somewhere else

# I need to close 'COM12' like this
# but can't access it because its already opened
dev.close()
```

Is there a way to force close a session like 'COM12' if it was opened in a different program? When other software (LabVIEW) encounters an error, it crashes and often leaves COM ports open, which then prevent me from accessing them without manually shutting down the physical device. It would be nice to force them to close so that they can be opened again properly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that if LabVIEW crashes, the operating system releases all hardware resources on its behalf.

But keep in mind that LabVIEW is a runtime environment in which child programs run.  So if the child program aborted, the LabVIEW process itself might still be running.  It would be easy to write a small LabVIEW program that calls VISA Close on COM12 within the LabVIEW environment and that should do the trick.  You could also quit the LabVIEW process.

Finally, I've occasionally seen serial device drivers (especially for non-standard serial ports, such as those that use USB or Ethernet) that run into problems if you the program doesn't do everything perfectly, such as gracefully call close.  In those cases, sometimes you have to reboot to get the device driver into the right state.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have a definitive answer, I'm pretty sure it's: No. As in, there's no good way to accomplish that.

Hardware resources are handled by the operating system. And if one process opens a resource and does not release it, you cannot just go and steal it "without consent". That would crash the other process. Which the operating system is tasked to prevent.

You may be able to "kill" the other process, using the operating system's API. But you would first have to identify it as the one holding the lock on the given resource — which would be the topic of another question.